# Is there a way to disable bibdata/bibstyle in the article class (like \nocite) in Texmaker

Tags: bibliographies, texmaker

I want to use the article class for homework I'm going to write up which I don't need a bibliography for.  Citations I'm able to disable but TexMaker complains that it found no bibdata or bibstyle - I want to disable this as well with a command.  Is that possible?

```
  \documentclass[english,11pt]{article}


  \usepackage{amsthm}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{babel}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{times}
  \usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}

  \newlist{Problem}{enumerate}{1}
  \setlist[Problem]{label=UR-\arabic*:}

  \begin{document}

  \title{Homework 1}
  \author{Name}
  \date{\today}
  \maketitle 

\begin{Problem}
    \item First
    \item Second    
\end{Problem}

  \nocite{*}


  \end{document}
```

Comment: Do not include `\bibliography` in your latex document.

Comment: @Guido I don't have that.  I've added the LaTeX code.  Could be some option in Texmaker but not sure what

Comment: It was due to the default quick build option.  I'm good now

Comment: The `\nocite{*}` command means add all entries in the bib file to the bibliography even though they have not been cited in the main text.  I think you just need to remove that command.

Comment: @AndrewSwann - it was the quick build option.  I tested it to be sure - removing nocite still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with the Quick Build default option that includes "Biblatex" regardless of what I have in the body.  I switched to a different quick build and now I do not get those messages

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{comment}   
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,newverbs,xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\title{...}
\author{..}
\date{March 2021}
\def\refex#1#2{\ref{ex:#1}.\ref{it:#1.#2}}
\marginsize{1.2cm}{1.5cm}{1cm}{1cm}
\begin{document}
```

I seem to have the same problem using Overleaf online compiler. I don't have used any bibliography-like packages nor any references to citations. I also don't have any command using the word bibliography but I still get the warning:

> BibTeX: No data sources defined!

I would like to get rid of this warning because I don't think its appeareance makes any sense at all. I think that maybe documentclass article has bibtex by default but I got the same when I changed to report. So I only want to disable this default option in my overleaf project if it's possible.